# Is it necessary to call a function/method outside the main body

Tags: java

Im currently learning java. SO I had this Question if it is necessary to create a method or function(create a class) outside the main body and then create its object and call it in main body?

Comment: Can you show some code snippet that demonstrates your question?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. At some point, your `main` will become extremely large so you can't manage it.

Answer (score 2):

There's several answers:

1. It is *possible* to have all the code of your program in a single main method and not split it into multiple methods or classes. That restricts what exactly you can do, but you could still get pretty far with that.
2. It's a terribly bad idea to do that, since your code will become really hard to read and you can't easily encapsulate individual sub-tasks and many design patterns won't be usable in such an environment
3. There is a technical restriction which limits how far you can go with that in Java and that is that the byte code of a single method can not exceed 64k bytes.

*tl;dr*: yes, but you shouldn't. Also no, you can't (for any serious code).

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can put *all* your application's code into the main method (without creating any other methods or classes): Yeah, I guess, but it is better to structure your code into smaller pieces. And there is a size limit for a method.

Also see:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141563/should-main-method-be-only-consists-of-object-creations-and-method-calls
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/why-is-it-good-to-split-a-program-into-multiple-classes

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to create a method/function outside the main body and then call it in main body, but if your code line in main is more i.e. 1000 or 2000 line then it is very difficult to manage code. So, if you create method outside main (In other class file) then call in main method using object then your code will be more readable.

Comment: "Difficult to manage" begins a lot sooner than 1000 or 2000 lines!  As a general rule, an method too long to fit in one screen page (about 50 or 60 lines) is too big.

Comment: It really helped me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the concept of object orientation in Java. You are not forced to use objects and methods apart from `main`, but I would really reccomended it. Java is instead of C based languages not procedural but object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

As vimal said, This totally depends upon your code.
This question is not only limited to java but to all other languages too.
Suppose you are making an movie booking application for the explanation of this answer.

Then writing the whole code inside(Booking a ticket, deleting a ticket, Paying for a ticket purchased, and so on) main function would not be a good idea. One may think to write whole code in main method but it will make the code more tedious and complex. Whereas if you write your code in different functions, It will make your code modular, And also it will make your code easier for others to understand. Hope this helps to clear question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You can do both, but there is a huge difference between them.

Java follows OOP paradigm. When you are defining a method outside your main(), you are associating the method with the class. You are defining the behaviour of a class.

However, if you are defining a method within main(), then it's just like any other method. You can call them as per your requirement.